# What is the difference between gawk and mawk with regards to field separators?

Tags: awk

What is the difference between gawk and mawk with regards to field separators?  In particular, I'm trying to figure out what is going on here:

mawk:

```
$ echo "100+50°20.5" | mawk -F '[+°.]' '{ print $1" - "$2" - "$3" - "$4" - "$5; }'
100 - 50 -  - 20 - 5
```

gawk:

```
$ echo "100+50°20.5" | gawk -F '[+°.]' '{ print $1" - "$2" - "$3" - "$4" - "$5; }'
100 - 50 - 20 - 5 -
```

It looks like mawk is introducing an extra field somehow.  What is the correct behavior?

Comment: see the `-b` (`--characters-as-bytes`) switch of the GNU awk or pass `LC_ALL=C gawk` or `LC_ALL=C mawk` for the same result; see also [Locales- Where You Are Makes A Difference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Locales.html)

Comment: The important (and not necessarily obvious) thing here is `°` is a multi-byte character.

Comment: See also https://github.com/ThomasDickey/original-mawk/issues/43

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Or at least, `°` is multi-byte _in UTF-8_. (I remember the days when people could be using all sorts of character encodings, and you couldn't make any assumptions at all! Things are much better now that UTF-8 is the default, but it's not yet universal.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To understand what’s happening here, look at the bytes provided as input to AWK:

```
$ od -t x1 <<<"100+50°20.5"
0000000 31 30 30 2b 35 30 c2 b0 32 30 2e 35 0a
0000015
```

In UTF-8, “°” is a multi-byte character, represented by 0xC2 0xB0. [MAWK doesn’t support multi-byte characters](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/original-mawk/issues/43), so it treats the regular expression provided as a field separator as matching one of the four bytes 0x2B (“+”), 0xC2 (“°” part one), 0xB0 (“°” part two), and 0x2E (“.”). These match four times in the input string, resulting in five fields:

- “100”
- “50”
- the empty string (between 0xC2 and 0xB0)
- “20”
- “5”

GAWK takes the current locale into account and supports multi-byte characters by default, so it matches “°” as a character and finds four fields. This can be disabled by using the `-b` option or by switching to a non-multi-byte locale with `LC_ALL=C`.

Answer (score 15):

As wisely explained in StephenKitt and in the comments, `°` multibyte char
is being split in `[°]` context...

One way to get around this is to use the "or" regex operator:

```
awk -F '[+.]|°' ...
```